# Disable hyper-threading for better Solr performance?

Tags: java, multithreading, solr, lucene, hyperthreading

I have a machine with 16 real cores (32 with HT enabled).
I'm running on it a Solr server and trying to reach maximum performance for indexing and queries (indexing 20k documents/sec by a number of threads).
I've read on multiple places that in some scenarios / products disabling the hyper-threading may result in better performance results.
I'm looking for inputs / insights about HT on Solr setups.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking it yourself?

Comment: Check this, in case if you have not yet - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81204/hyperthreading-mysql-innodb-thread-concurrency-performance

Comment: This is an interesting question. I suggest you take it up on the solr users mailing list where some experts can guide you.

Comment: @chrylis I didn't benchmark myself yet since doing the benchmark right requires making sure that Solr is fully optimized in both setups which requires in depth analysis and understanding. I hope to get to it at some point.